# iterate object array and update properties

Tags: javascript

I receive arrays of objects with that structure, I'm trying to be able to go through them and concatenate a variable, and that the links are as follows

```
link: `${id}/users`
link: `${id}/add-user`
```

...

```
id= school1;

dashboardMenu = [
    {
      title: "Dashboard",
      icon: "home-outline",
      link: "/",
      home: true,
      children: undefined,
    },
    {
      title: "Users",
      icon: "person-outline",
      link: "/users",
      data: "read:users",
      children: [
        {
          title: "Users",
          link: "/users",
          data: "read:users",
        },
        {
          title: "Create User",
          link: "/add-user",
          data: "create:users",
        },
      ],
    }
 ]
```

Comment: I already corrected it, sorry.@Barmar

Comment: What problem are you having? Loop through the objects, and do `obj.link = id + obj.link`

Comment: and with that, I return a new array of objects, with that concatenated variable?

Comment: No, you modify the objects in place rather than return a new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try mapping through the object and it's children and then prepend the `id`, like:

```js
let id = "school1";
let dashboardMenu = [
  {
    title: "Dashboard",
    icon: "home-outline",
    link: "/",
    home: true,
    children: undefined,
  },
  {
    title: "Users",
    icon: "person-outline",
    link: "/users",
    data: "read:users",
    children: [
      {
        title: "Users",
        link: "/users",
        data: "read:users",
      },
      {
        title: "Create User",
        link: "/add-user",
        data: "create:users",
      },
    ],
  },
];

let result = dashboardMenu.map((o) => {
  o.link = id + o.link;
  if (o.children) {
    o.children.forEach((child) => (child.link = id + child.link));
  }
  return o;
});

console.log(result);
```

Recursively you could do something like:

```js
let dashboardMenu = [{
    title: "Dashboard",
    icon: "home-outline",
    link: "/",
    home: true,
    children: undefined,
  },
  {
    title: "Users",
    icon: "person-outline",
    link: "/users",
    data: "read:users",
    children: [{
        title: "Users",
        link: "/users",
        data: "read:users",
      },
      {
        title: "Create User",
        link: "/add-user",
        data: "create:users",
      },
    ],
  },
];

setNestedLink = (o, k, id) => {
  if (o[k]) {
    o[k] = id + o[k];
    if (o.children) {
      o.children.forEach((child) => setNestedLink(child, k, id));
    }
  }
  return o;
};


let result = dashboardMenu.map((o) => setNestedLink(o, "link", "school1"));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Use `forEach` instead of `map` if you're not using the result.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat#Performance) strongly recommends using `+=` rather than the `concat()` function.

Comment: Thank you for the tip @Barmar, I think I've been doing too much react :) Simplified my answer based on your feedback.